# Knockout JS initializing observable array from server data using a javascript type

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm looking for the best way to initialize a knockout observable array from some server data (ViewBag), and I want the array contents to be of a javascript type I have defined. Without the requirement of the JS type I could just use:

```
materialVarieties: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Materials)))
```

but I also have a material JS type that I want to use so I can have some extra ViewModel specific properties and functions i.e.:

```
var material = function(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);

    this.select = function()
     {
        jQuery.each(processViewModel.materials(), function(index, item)
        {
            item.selected(false);
        });
        this.selected(true);
      }
}
```

And then the required initialization becomes:

```
materialVarieties: ko.observableArray([new material(1, "Apricot"), .....
```

Currently I build up a string from the ViewBag data and then render that as the initializer like this:

```
@{ var items = string.Join(",",
                ((IEnumerable<MaterialVariety>) ViewBag.Materials)
                            .Select(m => string.Format("new material({0}, {1})",
                                      Json.Encode(m.Id), Json.Encode(m.Name)))); }

var processViewModel = {
    material: ko.observableArray([@Html.Raw(items)])
```

But I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way than the `string.Join` bit. I could wrap it up in a Helper. What do you do?

Comment: Why not create a HtmlHelper extension method? Take a generic argument and return the encoded output.

Comment: @Anuj Yeah thats what I was thinking ('I could wrap it up in a Helper'), it'd also have to have a string representing the JS type. Problem comes when working out the properties to use in the JS constructor (and the order required). I can reflect the generic argument to get the properties, but I was hoping to use my server side Models (don't want another set of server side VMs) and they have other properties that I don't need in my JS. And that still leaves me the problem of the constructor arg order.....unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would typically serialize the array first, then map it when putting it in the view model.  Would be like:

```
var originalVarieties = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Materials))

var processViewModel = {
   materialVarieties: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(originalVarieties, function(variety) {
      return new material(variety.id, variety.name);
   }))
}
```

Requires a minor amount of additional processing on the client-side, but seems cleaner than building strings.

Comment: ah, that looks good. I am new to Knockout and was unaware of utils.arrayMap. Thank you.

Comment: yep, there is nothing special about ko.utils.arrayMap. Pretty simple code.  jQuery map would do the same.